# Could someone help me build the elequent query laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am on laravel, I am developing a library. I would like to display a list of books with a publication date of less than 3 months. Could someone help me build the elequent query. I tried with the DB class but it doesn't work.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$books = DB::select("SELECT * from books where(DATEDIFF($today, 'publication_date') <=90)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can benefit from [laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) and pass `now()->subDays(90)` as the point that the date must be greater than.

```
DB::table('books')
                ->whereDate('publication_date', '>', now()->subDays(90))
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) package that comes with Laravel is quite handy for these types of thing.

What you could do is the following:

```
$books = Book::where('published_date', '<=', now()->addMonths(3))->get();
```

Comment: I did not install the carbon package

Comment: @selfself You don't need to install it, it comes with Laravel.